# Moving wordpress website with data changed from Azure account to another account on Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure-web-app-service

I have installed wordpress website on my Azure account then I imported all the data in additional that I made a lot of changes in the theme.

Now, I want to move this wordpress website from this account to another account on Azure and I already downloaded the theme in additional to plugins then I uploaded to this account but it seems that I make all changes from scratch so, what is the exact steps that I should follow to move this wordpress website with data that I already changed it to the other account on Azure ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are both the accounts under same tenant?

If so, we can migrate the resources in one resource group to another.

You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources) article.

Moving a resource only moves it to a new resource group. The move operation can't change the location of the resource. The new resource group may have a different location, but that doesn't change the location of the resource.